# How to extract exact data from a file?

Tags: bash, pid, tail, lsof

I have used this command - `lsof +D /usr/bin` and generated following output -

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
metacity  1347  gdm  txt    REG    8,1   609760 278555 /usr/bin/metacity
tail      1474 root  txt    REG    8,1    59704 269067 /usr/bin/tail
```

Now I want to extract `1474` from above output and I am trying to use following command

```
lsof +D /usr/bin | grep "tail">tailfind.txt
```

But this command is injecting following information -

```
tail      1474 root  txt    REG    8,1    59704 269067 /usr/bin/tail
```

Now help me to get only specific column from the above operations.

Thanks and regards,
Shah9il

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `awk` for searching input and printing specific column(s):

```
lsof +D /usr/bin | awk '/tail/{print $2}'
```

Comment: Might be good to change the `awk` condition to `/^tail /` to avoid catching other programs that happen to have "tail" in their name...

Comment: Yes I agree that will be safer. I just used what OP was using in `grep`